# Uploading and Prasing XML into ruby on rails. Using importer or another such as Nokugiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hello i have a question about active record and importing XML.
I was asked if i could import a xml file into are website to add orders.
So say a client has a bulk order.

His system outputs already a XML file and i need to import it. I found a gem called importer.
It seems very good, as it does both XML and CSV imports ideal for what i need. However in the DOC's it says for imports

```
Product.import(path_to_file)
```

But i would like to make it into a button were they may select a file to import. I think i would use something like paperclip to do this. However if you have any method to do it. Even if it does not include importer. Maybe Nokugiri. Then please help.

Thank you for your time, I will be monitoring this post closely.

Comment: If you send me a link of which gem exactly you're talking about, I can give you a more precise answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Unless you want to save the file, all you need is a tool that reads it and converts the results to something that can be inserted into the database. Since you already found one, you just need to import it:

Add to your view a form for file insertion:

```
<%= form_tag import_products_path, multipart: true do %>
      <%= file_field_tag :file %>
      <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
    <% end %>
```

Add a custom route action:

```
resources :product do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

Put the `import` method in the controller:

```
def import
  Product.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

You do the processing in the model. For example:

```
  require 'nokogiri'

 def self.import(file)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(file)
    #your processing code goes here
 end
```

Comment: Ok i appreciate your input. Im going out for lunch right now. I will be back later to check this method.

Comment: I have a class called Order i dont have product so what should i substitute in the routing for import_products_path ?

Comment: you can check it by running  'rake routes' in the terminal and checking the route after you add it to routes.rb . I suppose it is import_orders_path

Comment: The only import route 
import_order_index

But then i get :

is undefined local variable or method `import_order_index' for #<#<Class:0x007f8dc11208d0>:0x007f8dbfbaeb50>

Comment: Than you, i forgot to add _path